# Store a counter in a binary tree recursive function in java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am doing an exercise for school where I have to create a method in java (at most O(n) time) that stores the order in which a given value appears in a binary tree, whether in post-order, in-order or pre-order traversal. So far I have working code, but the counter doesn't increment properly. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? My code is as follows:

```
public class Node {

int value;                // data used as key value
Node left;                // this node's left child
Node right;               // this node's right child
int preorderNumber; // node number in preorder
int inorderNumber; // node number in inorder
int postorderNumber; // node number in postorder


public Node(int item) { //instantiates node.
    value = item;
    left = right = null;
    preorderNumber = inorderNumber = postorderNumber = 0;
}
```

}

```
/* Given a binary tree, print its nodes according to the postorder traversal. */
private void printPostorder(Node node) {
    int counter = 0;

    if (node == null) { //the tree is empty. 
        return;
    }
    printPostorder(node.left); // first recur on left subtree 
    printPostorder(node.right); // then recur on right subtree
    System.out.print(node.value + " "); // now deal with the node
    counter++;
    node.postorderNumber = counter;
}

/* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in inorder*/
private void printInorder(Node node) {
    int counter = 0;

    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    printInorder(node.left);   // first recur on left child
    System.out.print(node.value + " "); // then print the data of node
    counter++;
    node.inorderNumber = counter;
    printInorder(node.right); // now recur on right child 
}

/* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in preorder*/
private void printPreorder(Node node) {
    int counter = 0;

    if (node == null) { //binary tree is empty. 
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(node.value + " "); // first print data of node.
    counter++;
    node.preorderNumber = counter;
    printPreorder(node.left); //  recur on left subtree 
    printPreorder(node.right); // now recur on right subtree 
}

public int find(int valueToFind) { 
    Node current = root, prior = null; 
    while (current != null) {
        int compare;
        compare = (valueToFind - current.value);
        if (compare < 0) {
            prior = current;
            current = current.left;
        } else if (compare > 0) {
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The node value searched for is : " + valueToFind);
            System.out.println("The in order value is: " + current.inorderNumber);
            System.out.println("The post order value is: " + current.postorderNumber);
            System.out.println("The pre order value is: " + current.preorderNumber);
            return current.value;
        }
    }
    return prior == null ? null : prior.value;
}
```

}

Whenever I try to run this however, I get something like the following output:

The number of nodes is :2
Preorder traversal of binary tree is 
3 4 
Inorder traversal of binary tree is 
3 4 
Postorder traversal of binary tree is 
4 3 
The node value searched for is : 4
The in order value is: 1
The post order value is: 1
The pre order value is: 1

I'm not sure how to pass the value of the counter to the node, so that it holds the right value (In this case, 2, 2 and 1). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get counter from prv value. Otherwise it will be reset all the time. do it like below

```
private void printPostorder(Node node) {

    if (node == null) { //the tree is empty. 
        return;
    }

    int counter = node.postorderNumber;

    printPostorder(node.left); // first recur on left subtree 
    printPostorder(node.right); // then recur on right subtree
    System.out.print(node.value + " "); // now deal with the node
    counter++;
    node.postorderNumber = counter;
}
```

pre-order method also should change like that otherwise counter is not incremented